Puedo ejecutar Apps script en google site?
Tal cómo puse en el titulo, hice una aplicación web utilizando google sheets y apps script, la misma cuenta con un archivo.gs y 4 archivos.html yo pretendia migrar la misma en google site, pero no tuve suerte, me da error, alguien sabe si se puede desarrollar de algun modo la misma?

Bienvenido al sitio, te sugerimos revisar [ask]. Que error obtienes? que realizaste?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Puedes crear una aplicación web usando Google Apps Script y embeberla en una página del nuevo Google Sites. Los detalles se encuentran en la guía oficial: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web.
A continuación y copia de la versión en español de la sección correspondiente sin formato :

Incorpora tu aplicación web en Google Sites

Advertencia: Las apps web incorporadas todavía están sujetas a permisos de acceso para evitar el uso malicioso. Si tu aplicación web incorporada no funciona, verifica si los permisos establecidos por el propietario de la aplicación web y el administrador del dominio permiten su uso.

Para incorporar una aplicación web en Google Sites, primero se debe implementar. También necesitas la URL implementada del cuadro de diálogo Deploy.
Para incorporar una app web en una página de Sites, sigue estos pasos:
Abre la página de Sites en la que quieras agregar la aplicación web.
Selecciona Insertar > Incorporar URL.
Pega la URL de la app web y, luego, haz clic en AGREGAR.
La app web aparece en un marco en la vista previa de la página. Cuando publicas la página, es posible que los visitantes del sitio deban autorizar la aplicación web antes de que se ejecute normalmente. Las aplicaciones web no autorizadas presentan mensajes de autorización al usuario.

